How to swap 2 corners on 4x4x4 cube while keeping the cube's all other pieces intact?
There's a parity problem that might happen when solving the 4x4 cube when 2 corners should be swapped. In all the videos I saw when ceasing the parity problem they are doing such an algorithm which also changes some edges, but I'd like to know which is not changing anything else, just the 2 corners...

Can you post a picture?

Could you switch two adjacent cubes?

https://alg.cubing.net/?puzzle=4x4x4&title=Notation%20Demo&alg=2R2_U2_2R2_Uw2_2R2_2U2_U-_L_U-_R_U2_L-_U_R-_L_U-_R_U2_L-_U_R-

What is the purpose of this question?
To solve the cube those edges need to moved.  The two edge pieces that appear to be in the right place are actually not.  If you label those edge pieces with stickers or marker or something while solved and then set the scramble, you would see that they are in a different position than initial.

@Lucenaposition why didn't you add you as an answer? so I can mark as a solution... thanks you anyway, it works :)
